# Getting Proxmox Virtual Machines with Networking working on So you Start (OVH) Dedicated Server

Tags: networking, dns, virtualization, lxc

I just recently got a So you Start.com dedicated server. I want to set up some virtual machines in it and some LXC containers.

I have created a Ubuntu 20.04 virtual machine and have been trying to get it to have network access (to the outside world) and can't seem to figure it out. I have tried to follow the [Proxmox Wiki guide for OVH](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/OVH) but I believe it is a bit outdated since it is using `/etc/network/interfaces` which from my understanding was used in older Ubuntu releases. From my reading I believe I need a Netplan configuration. I found [an article on the OVH site which speaks about setting up Ubuntu 18.04 VM](https://support.us.ovhcloud.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002394324-How-to-Connect-a-VM-to-the-Internet-Using-Proxmox-VE#ubuntu) so I tried following that guide.

Here is the configuration I created based on the guide for my networking:

```
# I have swapped the IP's to random ones.
# IP Address: 55.39.195.216
# Dedicated Server IP: 192.99.21.80
# CIDR: /29
# Using Cloudflare DNS resolvers
# NIC: I believe is ens19 per the `ip add` command.

network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
          ens19:
                  dhcp4: no
                  dhcp6: no
                  addresses: [55.39.195.216/29]
                  gateway4: 192.99.21.254
                  nameservers:
                          addresses: [1.1.1.1,1.0.0.1]
                  routes:
                  - to: 192.99.21.254/29
                    via: 0.0.0.0
                    scope: link
```

Also just to note the ip address I am trying to use here I created a virtual mac address for. The virtual mac address is entered in the Proxmox Hardware Networking section. In this config I also adjusted the gateway address to use the dedicated server IP but with the last octet switched to `254` as both the guides mentioned I needed to do this for OVH servers.

I then applied this config via `sudo netplan apply`. When I do `ping google.com` I get errors with being unable to resolve it. When I do `ping 8.8.8.8` it hangs and then fails.

I have been reading a bunch of different websites and I feel like I am a bit lost at this point with what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You configuration for the VM must be a /32 see chapter virtual machine from : https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/dedicated/network-bridging/ So you create a VM you need to a PUBLIC IP , so in S.Y.S. a fail-over IP and you need to create a virtual MAC for this IP . And after you need to update your VM with the virtual MAC . https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/dedicated/network-virtual-mac/

Comment: I already have a virtual mac and have it selected as the networking that is being used on the VM.